# How to create a basic Tooltip in React where you don't actually wrap the anchor element in another DOM element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

Most of the APIs for Tooltips in React I've seen work something like this:

```
<Tooltip title="Hello World">
  <span>hover me!</span>
</Tooltip>
```

What that ends up creating is a wrapper around that span, something like this:

```
<div>
  <span>hover me!</span>
</div>
```

On that div, now, you can add your mouseenter/leave handlers and such, and figure out the rest of the tooltip implementation. I am not concerned with all the other features for implementing a [robust React tooltip](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/blob/064249c2d344f5fa639d97994311e484a73156b4/src/index.js), but more wondering how from a technical perspective you go about wrapping that `<span>`, but without adding the extra `<div>`, I can't see how it can be done in React land (ideally with something like Portals).

If I use `React.cloneElement(child, { mouseenter: .... })` you run the risk of overriding the child's mouse handlers, but that is one possible way to do it. (I don't know how to basically do `super` here, get the passed in mouse handlers, and then wrap them with my own tooltip mouse handler, if they are present, any ideas?).

How would you go about implementing simply the *binding* part of a tooltip component, where it adds the handlers to the passed in child, using the above sort of API? Maybe you could also `cloneElement` and add a custom `ref` or something, but same override problem exists there and not sure how to work around that. Any help would be appreciated. To learn more React technical details, I would like to play around with making a basic tooltip, and see how you should approach this problem in React-land.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Tooltip({
  content,
  mouseEnterDelay = 200,
  mouseLeaveDelay = 500,
  children,
}) {
  const [portalContainer, setPortalContainer] = useState(typeof document !== 'undefined' && document.querySelector('#tooltip'))
  const [mouseEnterDelayTimer, setMouseEnterDelayTimer] = useState(null)
  const [mouseLeaveDelayTimer, setMouseLeaveDelayTimer] = useState(null)
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)

  const child = children

  const oldMouseEnterHandler = child.props.onMouseEnter
  const oldMouseLeaveHandler = child.props.onMouseLeave

  const clearMouseLeaveTimer = useCallback(() => {
    clearTimeout(mouseLeaveDelayTimer)
    setMouseLeaveDelayTimer(null)
  }, [mouseLeaveDelayTimer, setMouseLeaveDelayTimer])

  const clearMouseEnterTimer = useCallback(() => {
    clearTimeout(mouseEnterDelayTimer)
    setMouseEnterDelayTimer(null)
  }, [mouseEnterDelayTimer, setMouseEnterDelayTimer])

  const show = useCallback(() => {
    clearMouseEnterTimer()
    setIsVisible(true)
  }, [setIsVisible, clearMouseEnterTimer])

  const hide = useCallback(() => {
    clearMouseLeaveTimer()
    setIsVisible(false)
  }, [setIsVisible, clearMouseLeaveTimer])

  const handleMouseEnter = useCallback((e) => {
    oldMouseEnterHandler?.(e)
    console.log('handleMouseEnter', mouseLeaveDelayTimer)

    if (mouseLeaveDelayTimer) {
      clearMouseLeaveTimer()
      return
    }

    const timer = setTimeout(show, mouseEnterDelay)
    setMouseEnterDelayTimer(timer)
  }, [clearMouseLeaveTimer, oldMouseEnterHandler, setMouseEnterDelayTimer, show, mouseEnterDelay, mouseLeaveDelayTimer])

  const handleMouseLeave = useCallback((e) => {
    console.log('handleMouseLeave', mouseEnterDelayTimer)
    oldMouseLeaveHandler?.(e)

    if (mouseEnterDelayTimer) {
      clearMouseEnterTimer()
      return
    }

    const timer = setTimeout(hide, mouseLeaveDelay)
    setMouseLeaveDelayTimer(timer)
  }, [clearMouseLeaveTimer, mouseEnterDelayTimer, clearMouseEnterTimer, hide, setMouseLeaveDelayTimer, mouseLeaveDelay])

  const newChild = React.cloneElement(child, {
    onMouseEnter: handleMouseEnter,
    onMouseLeave: handleMouseLeave,
  })

  if (isVisible) {
    const portal = ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <div>{content}</div>,
      portalContainer
    )
    return (
      <>
        {portal}
        {newChild}
      </>
    )
  }

  return newChild
}
```

Comment: I noticed your example will cause some tooltips to stick if the mouse enter/leave action was too quick or the delay timing is too long: [demo](https://0fmw38.csb.app/). You can simplify some of the logic and leverage CSS to navigate around this: [demo](https://5sb78n.csb.app/), [source](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-portal-5sb78n?file=/src/Tooltip.tsx)

Comment: Yeah after tinkering with it a bit more, I wasn't able to fully get it working. The `mouseLeaveDelayTimer` and the like kept coming back null at random times instead of having the timer, I couldn't figure it out. But this at least (I think) answers the part about how to override the potential event handlers on a child node. Did you get it fully working perchance?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your ask as using a portal wouldn't require wrapping the child element. However, if you're asking how to do that AND have the tooltip be above the child element, then that'd require the usage of a ref and a fair amount of window calculation. On that note, you could avoid cloning the child element and instead utilize a child function render prop. For example, the `children` to Tooltip would a function that receives props from the Tooltip component: [source](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-children-function-prop-vge1mt?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: The render prop would allow you to conditionally apply the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` props to the child element (but that'd negate the tooltip functionality). That said, you could also pass down other props form the Tooltip component to the children like `setIsVisible` and `isVisible` state/state-setters and whatever else is housed within the Tooltip.